# How to handle a missing page.php?

Tags: page-template, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using the free Wordpress theme [Stargazer](https://wordpress.org/themes/stargazer) by Justin Tadlock.

I'm trying to integrate a plugin (WooCommerce) with it and after reading the documentation, I need to find the `page.php` file, copy the contents to a new file called `woocommerce.php` and replace the loop with `woocommerce_content()` function.

I can't seem to find the `page.php` file. Now what?

Comment: Usually it's in the themes folder, is it not there? Also you should only need to do that if you're doing some kind of customization. Finally, if you cannot find `page.php` it's probably best to try to that [theme specific support forum](http://themehybrid.com/support/forum/stargazer).

Comment: I gave your question a more general touch to keep it on topic. Hope you don’t mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

The only *required* template in a WordPress theme is the `index.php`. And a `comments.php` if comments are supported. Following the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), all other files, including `page.php`, will fall back to the `index.php`.

When a theme doesn’t have a `page.php`, look at the `index.php`. There you will find the basic structure for its content. In your example, the `index.php` looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); // Loads the header.php template. ?>

<main <?php hybrid_attr( 'content' ); ?>>

    <?php if ( !is_front_page() && !is_singular() && !is_404() ) : // If viewing a multi-post page ?>

        <?php locate_template( array( 'misc/loop-meta.php' ), true ); // Loads the misc/loop-meta.php template. ?>

    <?php endif; // End check for multi-post page. ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : // Checks if any posts were found. ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : // Begins the loop through found posts. ?>

            <?php the_post(); // Loads the post data. ?>

            <?php hybrid_get_content_template(); // Loads the content/*.php template. ?>

            <?php if ( is_singular() ) : // If viewing a single post/page/CPT. ?>

                <?php comments_template( '', true ); // Loads the comments.php template. ?>

            <?php endif; // End check for single post. ?>

        <?php endwhile; // End found posts loop. ?>

        <?php locate_template( array( 'misc/loop-nav.php' ), true ); // Loads the misc/loop-nav.php template. ?>

    <?php else : // If no posts were found. ?>

        <?php locate_template( array( 'content/error.php' ), true ); // Loads the content/error.php template. ?>

    <?php endif; // End check for posts. ?>

</main><!-- #content -->

<?php get_footer(); // Loads the footer.php template. ?>
```

You can strip all multi-post related code and the comments template call. And the unnecessary PHP tags and comments (*sigh*).  That leaves this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<main <?php hybrid_attr( 'content' ); ?>>

    <?php 
    if ( have_posts() )
    {
        while ( have_posts() )
        {
            the_post();
            hybrid_get_content_template();
        }

        locate_template( array( 'misc/loop-nav.php' ), true ); 
    }
    ?>
</main>

<?php get_footer();
```

That makes a nice readable `page.php`. You can now replace `hybrid_get_content_template();` with `woocommerce_content();` or whatever the plugin needs.

But wait! Do not change the theme, [create a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) instead and put your changes into *that*. Now you can still update the parent theme without losing your customizations.

You can follow these steps with every theme and every plugin. If the `index.php` works, you can use it to create new templates in a child theme.